# How to count horseshoes in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, numbers

I've completely stuck with this task and I really dunno how to make this program work properly, because I think I've already tried many possible options, but it still unfortunately didn't work properly.

The task is: "The blacksmith has to shoe several horses and needs to see if he has the correct number of horseshoes. Write a check(p, k) function that, for a given number of horseshoes p and number of horses k, prints out how many horseshoes are missing, remaining, or whether the number is correct (see sample file for output format)."

The code I've already done is:

```
def check(p, k):
    if p % 2 == 0 and k % 2 == 0 and p % k == 0:
        print("Remaining:", k % p)     
    elif p % k != 0:
        print("Missing:", p // k + 1)
    else:
        print("OK")

check(20, 6)
check(10, 2)
check(12, 3)
check(13, 3)
```

The output should look like this:

```
Missing: 4
Remaining: 2
OK
Remaining: 1
```

Comment: I assume a horse needs 4 shoes?

Comment: I've thought about that, but I still have no idea how to implement it

Comment: From my understanding, the blacksmith is "Missing" horseshoes if p < 4 * k; has "Remaining" horseshoes if p > 4* k; and "OK" when p == 4 * k. I think you have the if conditions and their body wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
def check(shoes, horses):
  if shoes > 4*horses:
     print("Remaining:", shoes - 4 * horses)
  elif shoes == 4*horses:
     print("OK")
  else:
     print("Missing:", 4 * horses - shoes)
```

Comment: Nice.  It would be clearer to choose the variable name as *needed* : ```needed = horses * 4```  and just do the calculation once.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking if you have the correct number first:

```
def check(p, k):
    required_shoes = k * 4
    if p == required_shoes:
        # just right
    elif p < required_shoes:
        # not enough
    else:
        # too many
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer was also helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

```
def check(p, k):
    if p / k == 4:
        print("OK")
    elif p / k > 4:
        print("Remaining:", p - 4 * k)
    else:
        print("Missing:", 4 * k - p)

check(20, 6) # Missing: 4
check(10, 2) # Remaining: 2
check(12, 3) # OK
check(13, 3) # Remaining: 1
```

This works in the given cases